# Can't install rails // Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I need help I've been stuck with this problem for a while, I'm trying to learn rails but I cant install Rails, I get this error :

ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /Users/rayzana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/racc-1.7.3/ext/racc/cparse
```

/Users/rayzana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/rayzana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/racc-1.7.3/ext/racc/cparse
make DESTDIR= sitearchdir=./.gem.20240226-72559-qrrjoe sitelibdir=./.gem.20240226-72559-qrrjoe clean
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

current directory: /Users/rayzana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/racc-1.7.3/ext/racc/cparse
make DESTDIR= sitearchdir=./.gem.20240226-72559-qrrjoe sitelibdir=./.gem.20240226-72559-qrrjoe
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/rayzana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/racc-1.7.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/rayzana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/extensions/x86_64-darwin-20/2.7.0/racc-1.7.3/gem_make.out

can anyone please help I've tried researching but I'm getting nothing

Im expecting to get rails installed